# SQL Find Corresponding Negative and Positive Records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, accounting

We have an accounting database implemented in SQL Server. The actual accounting records are int the `records` table with the following schema (names changed to protect the innocent + removed irrelevant columns).

```
`recordId` INT PRIMARY KEY
`amount` MONEY
`dateRecorded` DATE
`campaignYear` INT
`storeId` INT FOREIGN KEY (to the stores table)
`productId` INT FOREIGN KEY (to the products table)
```

Some bad records were added. Business rules prevented us from simply deleting the records, so they had to be zeroed out with negative records for the same amount (i.e. a $4,521 record gets zeroed out with a -$4,521 record).

The problem is that some of the negative records got tied to an incorrect productId.

**I need a query that shows all records with opposite amounts, within the same campaignYear, that are tied to different productIds.**

The result set would look something like this:

```
recordId   | amount   | dateRecorded | campaignYear | storeId | productId
11545      | 1132.13  | '2015-05-14' | 2015         | 45      | 1729
90463      | -1132.13 | '2015-08-02' | 2015         | 45      | 2402
25487      | 9300.00  | '2011-01-13' | 2010         | 122     | 85060
67953      | -9300.00 | '2014-06-06' | 2010         | 122     | 11348
01045      | 5045.99  | '2001-11-29' | 2001         | 3       | 105
32468      | -5045.99 | '2016-08-01' | 2001         | 3       | 109
```

Notice the same storeId but different productId for each pair of positive/negative records.

I don't really know how to go about this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `exists`.

```
select * from tablename t
where exists (select 1 from tablename t1
              where t.amount = -1*t1.amount 
              and t.productid <> t1.productid 
              and t.campaignyear = t1.campaignyear
              and t.storeid = t1.storeid)
```

Using `self-join`.

```
select t.* 
from tablename t
JOIN tablename t1 ON t.productid <> t1.productid 
and t.campaignyear = t1.campaignyear
and t.storeid = t1.storeid
WHERE t.amount = -t1.amount
ORDER BY t.storeid, abs(t.amount)
```

Comment: I like answers better that explain things, i.e. how you get to a query. (In this case: you look for records for which *exist* a sibling so use `EXISTS`). But the answer is correct nonetheless :-) I'd add `ORDER BY ABS(amount), campaignyear, storeid` so as to get the siblings next to each other.